# Combining OpenGL renderings into one view

Tags: opengl

I have a simple solid modeling application in which I want to implement several "navigation modes", ways for the user to navigate the camera through 3d space. One of them is the ubiquitous 'drag and pan/rotate' that is used in SketchUp, Blender etc.; I also want to implement something that is more relevant to my specific application. Specifically, I want to implement a mode where the camera floats on a 'ring' above the object being modeled (a building), and always looks at the center of the model; this way, a user can easily 'circle' around the object, a common operation in my application.

So, what I want to do is render the building in my view, and display a torus in the top right of the view, with a small sphere on the torus to represent the camera location. There would be a north arrow in the torus, and the user would drag the camera around the model object by dragging the sphere; moving the sphere would reposition the camera and redraw the scene.

It looks like what I should do is the following: render the 'main view', i.e. the building; then render the torus and sphere (with different perspective settings and lighting) to an offscreen buffer, and blit it from there to my main view.

Then however I get to the hit testing. I want to detect if the user clicks on the sphere, or the torus; from what I understand from OpenGL picking (it seems to be a hard subject :/ ), all picking methods apply only for selecting in one 'scene'. Apart from that, I still want to detect 'normal' picking operations in the building model, obviously.

So, my questions:

- How do I render to an offscreen buffer and blit into another OpenGL context (with alpha blending & transparence like for the center of the torus)?
- How do I do hit testing in the described scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to do off-screen rendering for this. You should be able to just re-set the camera and [viewport](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml) and render the overlay after the main scene. You might have issues with Z-ordering and/or buffering, but perhaps the "sub-scene" is simple enough for that not to matter, or you could of course just clear the Z buffer before rendering it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as drawing the torus/sphere goes, create a separate class for that and implement a "draw" method. Have the class contain the location of both the sphere and torus and have draw() render those things on the screen.

Then just call myRing.draw() in your main drawing method and you'll have a sphere and torus!

If you mean you want to have a a circle/ring rendered in 2D (which might be easier) in the top right corner of the window, then the same sort of idea would apply as in your hitbox post (except without that annoying projection calculation!)

Lastly, I'd consider using a function key in combination with mouse drags to implement the functionality you want... E.g. the user holds "shift" and then click-drags the mouse across the screen. These mouse events are caught and the x-delta is used to compute the angle of rotation. The camera's location is updated as this happens and you get a smooth sliding motion :)

Comment: Thanks, for completeness for future readers, here's the link to the post you mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829786/ways-to-implement-manipulation-handles-in-3d-view/830909#830909 . I think it's useful enough to repeat here, even though my idea for now is to render a 3d torus :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @unwind; you don't need an offscreen buffer. If you want to anyway, search for "render-to-texture".

As for hit testing, [The OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm) has an entry on it. It describes several solutions: using GL_SELECTION render mode, using gluUnproject() to get a 3D collision ray and a simple 2D solution using unique colors.